# SQL Multiple WHERE Clause Problem

Tags: php, sql

I'm attempting the modify this Modx Snippet so that it will accept multiple values being returned from the db instead of the default one.

tvTags, by default, was only meant to be set to one variable. I modified it a bit so that it's exploded into a list of variables. I'd like to query the database for each of these variables and return the tags associated with each. However, I'm having difficulty as I'm fairly new to SQL and PHP.

I plugged in $region and it works, but I'm not really sure how to add in more WHERE clauses for the $countries variable.

Thanks for your help!

```
if (!function_exists('getTags')) {

    function getTags($cIDs, $tvTags, $days) {

        global $modx, $parent;

        $docTags = array ();

        $baspath= $modx->config["base_path"] . "manager/includes";
        include_once $baspath . "/tmplvars.format.inc.php";
        include_once $baspath . "/tmplvars.commands.inc.php";

        if ($days > 0) {
            $pub_date = mktime() - $days*24*60*60;
        } else {
            $pub_date = 0;
        }

        list($region, $countries) = explode(",", $tvTags);

        $tb1 = $modx->getFullTableName("site_tmplvar_contentvalues");
        $tb2 = $modx->getFullTableName("site_tmplvars");
        $tb_content = $modx->getFullTableName("site_content");
        $query = "SELECT stv.name,stc.tmplvarid,stc.contentid,stv.type,stv.display,stv.display_params,stc.value";
        $query .= " FROM ".$tb1." stc LEFT JOIN ".$tb2." stv ON stv.id=stc.tmplvarid ";
        $query .= " LEFT JOIN $tb_content tb_content ON stc.contentid=tb_content.id ";
        $query .= " WHERE stv.name='".$region."' AND stc.contentid IN (".implode($cIDs,",").") ";
        $query .= " AND tb_content.pub_date >= '$pub_date' ";
        $query .= " AND tb_content.published = 1 ";
        $query .= " ORDER BY stc.contentid ASC;";

        $rs = $modx->db->query($query);
        $tot = $modx->db->getRecordCount($rs);
        $resourceArray = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$tot;$i++)  {
            $row = @$modx->fetchRow($rs);
            $docTags[$row['contentid']]['tags'] = getTVDisplayFormat($row['name'], $row['value'], $row['display'], $row['display_params'], $row['type'],$row['contentid']);   
        }
            if ($tot != count($cIDs)) {
            $query = "SELECT name,type,display,display_params,default_text";
            $query .= " FROM $tb2";
            $query .= " WHERE name='".$region."' LIMIT 1";
            $rs = $modx->db->query($query);
            $row = @$modx->fetchRow($rs);
            $defaultOutput = getTVDisplayFormat($row['name'], $row['default_text'], $row['display'], $row['display_params'], $row['type'],$row['contentid']);
            foreach ($cIDs as $id) {
                if (!isset($docTags[$id]['tags'])) {
                    $docTags[$id]['tags'] = $defaultOutput;
                }
            }
        }
            return $docTags;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't add in more `WHERE` clauses, you use `AND`s and `OR`s in the already existing where clause. I would say after the line `$query .= " WHERE stv.name = '".$region...` you put in

```
foreach ($countries as $country)
{
    $query .= "OR stv.name = '{$country}', ";
}
```

but I don't know how you want the query to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It doesn't seem to work though as $countries isn't an array. I really just need to query the value contained in $region and return the tags associated with it, then query the value associated with $countries and return the tags with it. $region="region" and $countries="countries" Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh sorry, no problem. Same solution without the loop, `$query .= "OR stv.name = '{$countries}', ";`